# "At random" vs "Randomly"

Tags: difference, adverbs, phrases

Both "**[At random](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/at_random)**" and "**[Randomly](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/randomly)**" have the definition: "***Without method or conscious decision.***"

However, can we use them interchangeably?

- The explosions occurred **at random/randomly**.
- The winner was picked **at random/randomly**.

"**randomly**" is only an adverb and "**at random**" is a phrase. Can we place the phrase where the adverb goes and vice versa?

- I cut the cake **randomly/at random**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say

> The winner was picked at random.

That is, it was *an intentionally random choice*.

and

> The explosions happened randomly throughout the night.

That is, following no pattern or naturally occurring cycle, showing no signs of an intentional, methodical, or natural frequency.

Comment: How would you explain your choice?

Comment: From my sense of general preference of native speakers.   Competent speakers tend to prefer *Your name was chosen at random* over *Your name was chosen randomly*. I believe this preference stems from the nuance of the preposition **at**, a nuance which the adverbial ending **ly** does not have.

Answer (score 0):

Other than positioning in a sentence, there is no difference between **At Random** and **Randomly** and they can be used interchangeably.

i.e. **"At random"** comes after the verb, while **"Randomly"** can come either before or after the verb.

E.g.

> The winning numbers are *randomly* selected by a monkey.
>
> The winning numbers are selected *randomly* by a monkey.
>
> The winning numbers are selected *at random* by a monkey.

Here is an [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20random%2Crandomly&year_start=1940&year_end=2017&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20random%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crandomly%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cat%20random%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Crandomly%3B%2Cc1) of their usage